# Upload a Dataset to Mockaroo with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to upload a Dataset to Mockaroo.com with the Mockaroo API using Python.

- The format of the upload file is CSV
- If it works correctly, the Dataset should be available to use with Mockaroo schemas

I am missing something - the CSV file uploads, but the format is wrong.

My code looks like this:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.multipart.encoder import MultipartEncoder
import uuid

mockaroo_api_key = "XXXXXXXXXX"
url = "https://api.mockaroo.com/api/datasets/customer"

csv_data = '''"customer_id", "customer_name"
"84a635ad-9518-4282-ad0f-3557f5d85f03","A"
"022096c3-8d09-4a33-a088-14ec8cac5459","B"
"06eccb26-72ad-4790-8818-cfa2f2ee1cf2","C"
"08d2b709-a86b-49ca-9618-03f1451991bf","D"
"64f6d8ae-ac64-466e-ad42-bac62c93b61e","E"
"9234c861-e8aa-40b9-8e81-13437a22fdeb","F"
"43114a05-2934-4bb2-a5c9-6baceb9a450e","G"
"1e40c936-3292-4b99-80d7-98f182def365","H"
"e3dafab3-6608-47b1-a67e-b0fbdcdb9c0b","I"
"305fa1c5-f082-40b8-8dbc-82b0322fe0b5","J"
'''

boundary = uuid.uuid4().hex
m = MultipartEncoder(fields={'body': ('customer.csv', csv_data, 'text/csv')}, boundary=boundary)
headers = {'Content-Type': m.content_type}

params = {'key': mockaroo_api_key, 'filename': 'customer.csv'}
response = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers, data=m)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

I get a 200 response and the file uploads successfully.  However, when I review the contents of the uploaded file on Mockaroo, it looks like this:

```
--72d8375e507a4716a4db93a5a72ad088
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="body"; filename="customer.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv

"customer_id"
"84a635ad-9518-4282-ad0f-3557f5d85f03"
"022096c3-8d09-4a33-a088-14ec8cac5459"
"06eccb26-72ad-4790-8818-cfa2f2ee1cf2"
"08d2b709-a86b-49ca-9618-03f1451991bf"
"64f6d8ae-ac64-466e-ad42-bac62c93b61e"
"9234c861-e8aa-40b9-8e81-13437a22fdeb"
"43114a05-2934-4bb2-a5c9-6baceb9a450e"
"1e40c936-3292-4b99-80d7-98f182def365"
"e3dafab3-6608-47b1-a67e-b0fbdcdb9c0b"
"305fa1c5-f082-40b8-8dbc-82b0322fe0b5"

--72d8375e507a4716a4db93a5a72ad088--
```

The contents should just be the CSV data.  What am I doing wrong?  Anyone have experience with the Mockaroo API using Python?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this myself - overthinking the multipart form.

```
response = requests.post('https://api.mockaroo.com/api/datasets/customer?key=' + mockaroo_api_key + '&filename=customer.csv',
    headers = headers,
    data = csv_data.encode('utf-8'))
```